# Making an AI program for a project. Can't get it to recognise the user input

Tags: c++, input, artificial-intelligence, declare

So I have to create an AI program than interacts with the user and responds based on the user input. I'm not very experienced, and this has already took hours lmao, I've looked online but I figured I'd actually post my code and try get some help/advice.

Basically the AI helps with maths, I have the program introducing itself and asking what it wants help with but when I enter Addition, Subtraction etc it just responds with numbers when it should respond with "Great, I'll help you with Addition!/(whatever user input)"

Screenshot of first running program: http://prntscr.com/elw7b4
Screenshot after entering what user needs help with: http://prntscr.com/elw7ky
(Obviously it's a bit all over the place at the moment, I did the calculator before anything else hence why it's giving additional results.

The calculator was working before entering the following code: (As you can see **http:// prntscr.com /elwavs** only two links cos haven't got more than 10 rep)

```
void Inpsum()
{

cout << "Hello, my name is Eva! I am able to help you with basic Maths! How may I be of Assistance today?" << endl;

float inpsum;

cin >> inpsum;

cout << "Great!, I will help you with " << (inpsum) << endl;
}
```

but entering the above code broke the calculator.

here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//user inputs what he needs help with/program output
void Inpsum()
{
   cout << "Hello, my name is Eva! I am able to help you with basic Maths! How may I be of Assistance today?" << endl;

cin >> inpsum;
cout << "Great!, I will help you with " << (inpsum) << endl;
}

//addition function
void Add() {
float add1, add2;
cout << "Please enter two values you want added together" << endl;
cin >> add1;
cin >> add2;
cout << "The answer is: " << (add1 + add2) << endl;
}

//subtraction function
void Subt() {
float subt1, subt2;
cout << "Please enter two values you want subtracted" << endl;
cin >> subt1;
cin >> subt2;
cout << "The answer is: " << (subt1 - subt2) << endl;
}

//division function
void Div()
{
    float div1, div2;
    cout << "Please enter two values you want divided" << endl;
    cin >> div1;
    cin >> div2;
    cout << "The answer is: " << (div1 / div2) << endl;
}

//multiplication function
void Mult() {
float mult1, mult2;
cout << "Please enter two values you want multiplacted" << endl;
cin >> mult1;
cin >> mult2;
cout << "The answer is: " << (mult1 * mult2) << endl;
}



int main()
{
Inpsum(); //user inputs what they want help with
Add();
Subt();
Div();
Mult();

    return 0 ; 
}
```

Basically - I've set the calculator up, and it was working. But upon trying to implement input and output between the user and the program I'm going wrong and have broken everything. Instead of the program saying "Great I'll help you with Addition", it says "Great, I'll help you with -134567432"

I'm not asking for anyone to do it for me, rather point me in the right direction so I can actually know what to do in the future.

Comment: Do you really think this is about the AI?

Comment: I have no idea what it's about hence why I'm here. We all start somewhere lol.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a good place to go to start. It is a good place to go after you have finished, and it still doesn't work. We can't teach you to program here.

Comment: Comments from live users, who know what they're looking at to point me in the right direction, rather than forum threads from 8 years ago seems a little better but point taken. My current code doesn't work and I have no idea why and so thought it would be a good place to ask.

Comment: @csfl0 You can start by thinking about this a little but. Do you think the problem you are encountering is because you're trying to code som AI related task, or maybe because you made a C++ mistake? Which of the two is more likely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice you define `inpsum` using `float inpsum;`, but what you are trying to store is string, or words. They are not compatible. You can learn something more about  data types and strings in C++.

Comment: Lmao I'm a moron. Thankyou

Comment: I think AI is not relevant to your question, maybe you need to be more specific next time, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It might help to use an enum since you only have a handful of choices. You could do something like this:

```
enum class OPERATION : char {
    Addition       = 'A',
    Subtraction    = 'S',
    Division       = 'D',
    Multiplication = 'M'
};
```

Then instead you cin to a string and have the following:

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;

switch(static_cast<OPERATION>(input[0])) {
    case OPERATION::Addition:
        Add();
        break;

    case OPERATION::Subtraction:
        Subt();
        break;

    case OPERATION::Division:
        Div();
        break;

    case OPERATION::Multiplication:
        Mult();
        break;

    default:
        std::cerr << "Invalid input" << std::endl;
        exit(1);

}
```

Defining the enum will allow you to cast values to it which match its values. This allows you to safely do a switch with defined inputs that you expect to see as your program runs.

Comment: Thank you for the help and your time!

Comment: This is a very constructive suggestion, you definitely should consider doing so